# What package is glib-sharp-3.0 in?

Tags: package-management, banshee

This messages comes from Banshee's configure script:

```
configure: error: Package requirements (glib-sharp-3.0 >= 2.99.1) were not met:

No package 'glib-sharp-3.0' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.
```

What package should I install?

Comment: Are you using the stable source code or the git development version?

Answer (score 3):

**Note**: this answer works with the current [stable source](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/banshee/2.6/banshee-2.6.0.tar.xz), but if you are using git you may need a new version of `glib-sharp` not provided by the repositories (see the end of the answer).

Using `apt-cache` we can search the required library with:

```
apt-cache search 'glib-sharp*'
```

which returns, among other files:

```
libglib2.0-cil-dev
```

So I should install this package and the other required packages with

```
sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-cil-dev libgconf2.0-cil-dev libgconf2-dev
```

and `sudo apt-get build-dep banshee`.

The package for `libglib2.0-cil-dev`, for example, notes that

> This package provides the glib-sharp assembly that allows CLI (.NET) programs
>   to use the GLib utility library 2.12. This is mostly useful for the GTK+ and
>   GNOME bindings.

It is also probably best to check the official `Banshee` requirements, and check that you have got all the required libraries as noted [at the official site](http://banshee.fm/download/development/#linux); if you are compiling the development version, other files and newer versions of them may be needed.

---

I just did a successful `configure` with the [latest stable source](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/banshee/2.6/banshee-2.6.0.tar.xz) and only had to install a couple of extra things:

```
sudo apt-get install boo libboo-cil-dev mono-gmcs
```

The latest stable version shouldn't require `glib-sharp-3.0`; in the configure report is the following:

Banshee-2.6.0:

```
(glib >= 2.22, gio-sharp >= 2.22.3, and gtk-sharp-beans)
```

---

However, if you are compiling from Git you will need to run `./autogen.sh` instead of `configure`, as noted on the [official site](http://banshee.fm/download/development/#linux). You may also need to get the `glib-sharp-3` file in this case from other sources or even compile some libraries, as the files you want may not be available in the repositories, so [the git sources here](http://banshee.fm/download/development/) might help.

Comment: Yes I've installed all those packages including `libglib2.0-cil-dev` but the error is still there

Comment: @szx This should work with the [stable source](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/banshee/2.6/banshee-2.6.0.tar.xz)

Comment: @user76204 I've downvoted your answer, the stable version of banshee has never required glib-sharp-3.0, he needs a new version that is still not packaged because he's compiling banshee master branch or a 2.9.x release, not stable

Answer (score 0):

Just install gtk-sharp3. I managed to get past it by installing that. Now I'm onto something else.